# Magento Admin theme changing extension

Tags: theme, extensions, admin-panel, customize

I require free extension In which I can change the Admin theme related things
like logos, color as in the below extension.

As this MageFan extension providing this :

https://magefan.com/magento-2-admin-view-extension

If any one have please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Hyvä Admin (https://github.com/hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-admin)?

Comment: I think this is for the Hyva, I am not using the Hyva Theme

Comment: No, you dont need the Hyvä on the frontend to use this theme. (source: https://github.com/hyva-themes/magento2-hyva-admin#relationship-with-frontend-hyv%C3%A4-themes)

Comment: Have you used this extension, if you have experience please let me know that Can I change the magento dashboard logos and color from the configuration by using this

Comment: Apologies, I have just installed it, and I can confirm you CAN NOT set logos and colors with configurations.

Comment: OH Any extension, with the set logos and colors with the configuratuions, Please if you have recommend me